# Improve performance in bulk upload in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I want to improve the db performance which is taking lot of time in bulk uplaod

```
  
is there any way i can improve the db performance for bulk upload.
```

Comment: Where is it specifically slow? How many accounts are you passing in one go? Not nearly enough info for any kind of answer. It looks like maybe 4 calls to the DB but we can't know because you don't list any code for any of your methods (`add_account_to_teams,  add_licences_to_account, account.assign_objectives_for, account.confirm`). Are you maxing your server during this? What is making you think the performance is poor?

Comment: It would be good to measure 1. which SQL statement is taking time and how much from the development logs. 2. If SQL dont take long to execute then maybe check if certain callbacks are executing which can be put to deferred execution. IMO you need to put in a lot more details to get a good suggestion for your problem. Also do check if you are performing any 3rd party calls like sending emails etc which can take time and **will** slow down the whole process and should be performed in the background.

Comment: What database are you using? If using PostgreSQL see here: https://pganalyze.com/blog/fastest-way-importing-data-into-postgres-with-ruby-rails